# Errno 2 No such file or directory: ffprobe

Tags: python, path, anaconda, spyder, ffprobe

I run Spyder through the Anaconda menu below.

[ANACONDA.NAVIGATOR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8q39.png)

Then I run a .py file which converts .m4a files to .mp3.

```
import os
import pydub
import glob

m4a_files = glob.glob('./*.m4a')

all_files = [m4a_files]

for files in all_files:
    for file in files:
        mp3_file = os.path.splitext(file)[0] + '.mp3'
        sound = pydub.AudioSegment.from_file(file)
        print("Converting: ",file)
        sound.export(mp3_file, format="mp3")
        os.remove(file)
        print("Conversion Complete")`
```

And it gives the following error:

```
    runfile('/Users/MyName/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Bibliothek/Deutsch/Wörterbuch/Soundaufnahmen/Wörterbuch_2000-3000_Original_Non-Equilazed/Converter_1.py', wdir='/Users/MyName/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Bibliothek/Deutsch/Wörterbuch/Soundaufnahmen/Wörterbuch_2000-3000_Original_Non-Equilazed')
    /Users/MyName/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydub/utils.py:198: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work
      warn("Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    
      File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
        exec(code, globals, locals)
    
      File ~/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Bibliothek/Deutsch/Wörterbuch/Soundaufnahmen/Wörterbuch_2000-3000_Original_Non-Equilazed/Converter_1.py:26
        sound = pydub.AudioSegment.from_file(file)
    
      File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydub/audio_segment.py:728 in from_file
        info = mediainfo_json(orig_file, read_ahead_limit=read_ahead_limit)
    
      File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydub/utils.py:274 in mediainfo_json
        res = Popen(command, stdin=stdin_parameter, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    
      File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py:1024 in __init__
        self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
    
      File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py:1917 in _execute_child
        raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffprobe'
```

I can see a folder named 'ffprobe' in the following directory:

/Users/MyName/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages

and I tried the following

```
sys.path.append('/Users/MyName/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages')
sys.path.append('/Users/MyName/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ffprobe')
```

but it didn't work.

I also tried to add the two directories above to the path by using Tools/PYTHONPATH Manager. However I can't get these directories to show up in the list of directories below:

[PYTHONPATH Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4p4BK.png)

Can you please help me with this?

Thank you all so much for your time.

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question and add the **whole** error traceback message.

Comment: Sorry, I'm an amateur coder and don't even know how to formulate my question. I have just added the entire error message. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffprobe'` error is not coming from your code directly, but is a consequence of some problem in the spyder/anaconda setup.

Comment: I don't know anything about spyder/anaconda, so I can't help further.

Answer (score 2):

I have just solved the problem by installing ffmpeg using the following command in the Terminal.

```
conda install ffmpeg
```